# Can't make a POST request to Github API

Tags: android, git, rest, android-volley, github-api

I am trying to make a POST request  to this URL :

"https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:%3E2018-12-29&sort=stars&order=desc"

using the parameters  : 'q' , 'sort' and 'order', but I get a message saying the 'q' code is missing.

[Request parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuiOl.jpg)

[Response message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2DrK.jpg)

It also doesn't work on my android volley using the POST method :

```
RequestQueue mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,"https://api.github.com/search/repositories", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("ANANAS","ONRESPONSE");
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("ANANAS","ONERROR");
            Log.d("ANANAS",error.getMessage());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
            params.put("q","created:>2018-12-13");
            params.put("sort","stars");
            params.put("order","desc");
            return params;
        }
    };

    mQueue.add(request);
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2):

Your parameters are fine, but you should use `Request.Method.GET` since the API will be expecting a GET (see [API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories)).

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,"https://api.github.com/search/repositories"
```